# Which one would have the biggest chance of winning?

Tags: statistics

This one is specifically unique (to me) though.

Say you want to win a prize. Said prize is given to only one person out of the three pools available. The pools are literally listed as the following:

- Prize pool 1.
- Prize pool 2.
- Prize pool 3.

As said before, pool 1 gives way one copy of the prize to one person, pool 2 too, and pool 3 the same as the two before.

If you could submit your name to one pool only, which one would you have the biggest probability of winning at?

I believe this problem has to do with [Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law), and thus for now I believe it would be #3, but I don't know if there are any other factors. Can someone confirm this or expand on the problem? Thanks a lot.

EDIT/Additional info:
And assuming there is a percentage of people who know about Benford's law, perhaps the safer bet is #2?

Comment: well, this is becoming a philosophical question. (EDIT: the last sentence of the OP gives it a philosophical touch)
I'm not overly familiar with Benford's Law but if people are allowed to choose themselves in which pool they are (rather than this is determined by a certain property, like the number of inhabitants in their home town), there should be approx the same number of people in each of the pools.

Comment: You should randomize you choice and pick each pool with equal probability. This will maximize worst case performance. See Nash Equilibrium.